# Chained `require` in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my `models` module:

*models/index.js:*

```js
module.exports = {
    Game: require('./game')
}
```

*models/game.js:*

```js
class Game {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
module.exports = Game;
```

**Here's the `db` module, where the problem resides:**

*db/game-db.js:*

```js
const GameModel = require('../models/game');  // this works. `GameModel` refers to the `Game` class
// const GameModel = require('../models').Game;  // `GameModel` is undefined
```

**Why doesn't the second `require` statement work as expected? Shouldn't it require the *models* module, which in turn requires *game.js* and then gives the `Game` class back to *game-db*? Is it due to some special mechanism of `require`?**

---

***Edit:***
Additional information: As @Thomas comments, the problem doesn't show up when running *db/game-db.js* with `node db/game-db.js`. It happens in my Express.js project. Any suggestions on how/where I should debug the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because you are requiring `models/Games` which is the game class, what you want to do is `const GameModel = require("../models").Game;` this requires the index.js file

Comment: @Ameer His question is why the `index.js` (`const GameModel = require("../models").Game;`) require statement results in `GameModel` being undefined.

Comment: @theusaf, I see, I misunderstood the question, thank you for clarifying!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I put `console.log('GameModel');` into `db/game-db.js` and run `node db/game-db.js`, it prints `[class Game]` as expected.

Comment: it should work, I use this structure all day long

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `models.js` in your filesystem?

Comment: @Thomas Oh! That's also something weird. It does work when running the game-db.js file alone with node. But the problem comes up when running this with the Express.js framework.

Comment: @theusaf Not really. But thanks for your idea anyway!

Comment: @Thomas Additionally, in db/game.js, `const models = require('../models'); console.log(models);` produces `{}` output, rather than what's exported in _models/index.js_. Does this information give anyone any clue?

Comment: So, this problem occurs when `db/game-db.js` is required from your express project? If so, could you post the code for your express project (and what file structure looks like, if needed). The only thing I can think of right now is that there is a `models.js` file located in the root folder.